# SQL code to join to, and sum data in, a table referenced by comma delimited keys

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq, t-sql

I have two tables like this:

```
InfoTable
-------------------
AVNR    Substation       ColumnTitle     S6_name      AVNRString
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1129     AHWAZ-1        T3+T4              MW          1129,1134
1130     AHWAZ-1        T3+T4              MX          1130,1135
1134     AHWAZ-1        T3+T4              MW          1129,1134
1135     AHWAZ-1        T3+T4              MX          1130,1135
8906     SHOMAL         T9                 MW             8906
8907     SHOMAL         T9                 MX             8907
```

and

```
DataTable
------------------------------------------------
Pdate           Ptime     AVNR        Wert
------------------------------------------------
03-13-2017      01:00     1129         12.65
03-13-2017      02:00     1129         25.65
03-13-2017      03:00     1129         102.05
03-12-2017      01:00     1129         12.65
03-14-2017      01:00     1129         12.65
03-16-2017      05:00     1129         12.65    
03-13-2017      01:00     1134         12.65
03-13-2017      02:00     1134         25.65
03-13-2017      03:00     1130         102.05
03-12-2017      01:00     1135         11.15
03-14-2017      01:00     1130         10.00
03-16-2017      01:00     8906         24.5
03-13-2017      01:00     8906         23.5
03-16-2017      02:00     8907         22.5
03-13-2017      01:00     8907         21.5
03-16-2017      05:00     8906         12.5
03-13-2017      02:00     8907         20.5
```

I want to have this result

```
 ResultTable
-------------------
Substation    ColumnTitle     S6_name   Pdate       pTime   Sum_of_Wert     
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 AHWAZ-1        T3+T4          MW      03-13-2017    01:00   25.3  (sum of Wert for 1129,1134  for that date and time)
 AHWAZ-1        T3+T4          MW      03-13-2017    02:00   51.3  (sum of Wert for 1129,1134  for that date and time)
 AHWAZ-1        T3+T4          MW      03-13-2017    03:00    xxx
 AHWAZ-1        T3+T4          MX      03-14-2017    01:00    xxx
 SHOMAL         T9             MW      03-13-2017    01:00    xxx
 SHOMAL         T9             MW      03-13-2017    02:00    xxx
```

......

i.e. I want to the sum value for `Substations` that are distinguished in `AvrString` for each date and time .

Is there by any chance I could do this in SQL ? I not, perhaps in Linq? I have programmed in visual studio, but this is slow. I want to know if there is any idea for that.

I am programming in c# in visual studio with sql database

Comment: Hint try Group BY

Comment: Just to add that you should use `GROUP BY` on the column `AVNR`

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Visit w3school for basic SQL server join and grouping concept. for current problem refer [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82353/2][1]

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that whomever designed the `InfoTable` didn't abide by the rules of proper [table normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form), and embedding strings like `1129,1134` indicating relationships between keys in other rows makes life very difficult.

If you are using a modern version of SQL Server - 2016 or later - your bacon is saved with the [STRING_SPLIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305493) function.

This will allow you to re-normalize the table (i.e. split out rows for each `AVNR` in `AVNRString`). You can then cast the split `AVNR` back to `INT` in order to join to this and apply it in a grouping, i.e.

```
WITH normalizeInfoTable AS
(
   SELECT it.Substation, it.ColumnTitle, it.S6_name, CAST(cs.Value as INT) as AVNR
   FROM InfoTable it
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (it.AVNRString, ',') cs
)
SELECT it.Substation, it.ColumnTitle, it.S6_name, dt.Pdate, dt.pTime, SUM(dt.Wert) 
  FROM normalizeInfoTable it
  INNER JOIN DataTable dt
  ON it.AVNR = dt.AVNR
  GROUP BY it.Substation, it.ColumnTitle, it.S6_name, dt.Pdate, dt.pTime;
```

[SqlFiddle up here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4bbc4/7)

**Notes**

The Info 'pairings' are duplicated in your table, i.e. the effect of

```
AVNR    Substation       ColumnTitle     S6_name      AVNRString
1129     AHWAZ-1        T3+T4              MW          1129,1134
1134     AHWAZ-1        T3+T4              MW          1129,1134
```

produces 4 rows as each of 1129 and 1134 will be duplicated twice each. If this isn't what's needed, then you can eliminate duplicates by adding a `DISTINCT` in the CTE, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT it.Substation, it.ColumnTitle, it.S6_name, CAST(cs.Value as INT) as AVNR
...
```

Also note that proper normalization is still preferred, since the `AVNR` relationships can be enforced with foreign keys, and performance improved with an index on this column. Applying `STRING_SPLIT` function has performance penalties.

Comment: this is awesome answer!

Comment: This is good answer thought STRING_SPLIT function only available since version SQL SERVER 2016. If any body use version before that then Split UDF need to be written first.

Comment: Yes, I highlighted this fact in Para 2.

Answer (score 1):

@StuartLC 's answer is awesome

here's anthor way for you 
"use `distinct` and `like`":

```
with CTE AS (
  select distinct [Substation], [ColumnTitle],[S6_name], [AVNRString]
  from InfoTable T1
)
select T2.Substation,T2.ColumnTitle, T2.S6_name,T1.Pdate,T1.pTime,sum(T1.Wert) Sum_of_Wert
from DataTable T1
left join InfoTable T2 on  
  T2.AVNRString = T1.AVNR
  or T2.AVNRString like '%,'+T1.AVNR+'%'
  or T2.AVNRString like '%'+T1.AVNR+',%'
group by T2.Substation,T2.ColumnTitle, T2.S6_name,T1.Pdate,T1.pTime
order by Sum_of_Wert
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39594/3/0)

---

**ps:**
thanks @dotnetstep

> In my opinion like is not good option if it does not explicit separator. In your case if T1 table has value 1129 ( AVNR) and AVNRString contains 1129,1134 and some other row contains 11290,1134 then also it will satisfy condition.

i try this condition script to avoid it.

```
   T2.AVNRString = T1.AVNR
      or T2.AVNRString like '%,'+T1.AVNR+'%'
      or T2.AVNRString like '%'+T1.AVNR+',%'
```

Comment: In my opinion like is not good option if it does not explicit separator. In your case if T1 table has value 1129 ( AVNR) and AVNRString contains 1129,1134 and some other row contains 11290,1134 then also it will satisfy condition.

Answer (score 0):

here a query with `STRING_SPLIT`

```
SELECT it.Substation,it.ColumnTitle,it.S6_name,dt.Pdate,dt.pTime, SUM(dt.Wert) AS Sum_of_Wert
FROM InfoTable it
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(it.AVNRString, ',') ) x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM DataTable  WHERE AVNR = CAST(x.value as INT) ) dt
GROUP BY it.Substation,it.ColumnTitle,it.S6_name,dt.Pdate,dt.pTime
```

SQL Fiffle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1ed2d/1